# Simply transfer HTML code into other HTML files

Tags: html

I would like to start a homepage for me. Every time I add a thing to index.html I have to add it to the links (in about.html etc.) as well.
How can I simplify that, that the new things of the index.html are automatically transferred directly into the other links (about.html etc.)?
Thanks for the help

Comment: If you're talking about shared HTML, like navigation or what not, use a web server that supports server side includes.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used was to create a JS script that you would include in your HTML, that would add the HTML you want to the document :

```
let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "your html");
```

You could then put this script where you want to include the HTML.
I don't know if it's the best solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, using vanilla HTML, there is no quick, easy, and simple way to do this. Using a backend framework like Django, this is easy, but that is really complicated and takes a while to learn!